# CSS webkit-keyframes work in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox?

Tags: css, cross-browser, webkit

The following works on Chrome and Safari, but not on Firefox. Any ideas why?
http://codepen.io/cory/pen/dILyo

Comment: You haven't used the moz prefixed or non-prefixed version of the keyframes syntax. **webkit** is a Chrome/Safari specific browser option.: **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't used the moz prefixed (old versions of FF) or non-prefixed version of the keyframes syntax.

**webkit** is a Chrome/Safari (and Opera+15) specific browser option.:

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes**

Comment: I'd say: `-webkit-` is just for Webkit (including Opera 15+)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the animation part. If you don't mind helping further, do you know how to make the ugly blue circles in the "ring" element appear as they do on Chrome/Safari?

Comment: Codepen is having issues at the moment but I'll look when it's back although you might copy to JSfiddle and post that link too.

Comment: Did you had a chance to check it? Thanks.